# Query RecordType of a Contact from WhoId of an Event or Task

Tags: record-type, relationships

I would like a list of all task/events which are concerning to a account record and and a contact record and the contact has a specific recordtype

I have the whoid, but how can I query the recordtype of the contact?

```
select Id, Subject, CreatedDate, StartDateTime, Createdby.Name, Owner.Name from Event where AccountId =: currentRecordId and Contact.RecordTypeId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find just contacts that match a given record type, use a subquery filter:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM Event 
WHERE AccountId = :currentRecordId AND 
WhoId IN
  (SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE RecordType.Name = 'ABC')
```

You can use either the Name or the RecordTypeId, as in your example, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

WhoId is a polymorphic relationship field (it can point to a Contact or a Lead).

The documentation on [Understanding relationship fields and polymorphic fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_and_polymorph_keys.htm) tells us that we can use `TYPEOF` to query related data for such fields.

e.g.

```
SELECT
    Id,
    TYPEOF Who
        WHEN Contact THEN RecordType.Name
    END
FROM Event
WHERE
    Who.Type = 'Contact'
```

Accessing the related data in Apex is then just like anything else. `myEvent.Who.RecordType.Name`

It doesn't appear that we can access that related data in the WHERE clause though, so that part of your filtering would need to be done in Apex.